# Getting resources from java project

Tags: java, eclipse, resources, project

So, my java project has the following hierarchy :

```
Project folder ------src-----PackageA-----MainClass (with main method)
          |       |
          |         -----PackageB------SecondClass
          ------resource----image.jpg
```

The src folder is on the classpath, but the resource folder is not(I don't know if this is the cause of my problem)

Here is the problem. When i try to use `getResourceAsStream()` from inside a method from SecondClass I get NullPointerException. I've tried

`getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resource/image.jpg")` 
`getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Project folder/resource/image.jpg")`
`getClass().getResourceAsStream("Project folder/resource/image.jpg")`

and in all the paths returned null pointer. I am sure I am doing something wrong but I don't get what. Please, help me out! Thanks!

Comment: "I don't know if this is the cause of my problem" In a word: yes, it is. Although your problem is more fundamental, in the sense that you don't want to put your source folder in the class path.

Comment: Your resource folder must be on the classpath.

Comment: Oh, ok than..thanks :)

Comment: But i seriously had no idea that was my problem